# Disable shopping cart / checkout / shipping

Tags: magento

Is there any way to disable the shopping card / checkout / shipping options in Magento?

I'm working on a product comparison site with prices listed from affiliate websites.

I'm not actually selling anything on my site per say.

Answer (score 4):

aDVo,if disable the below magento `Module Mage_Checkout from admin>System>Configuration> advance>Advance.`Then checkout cart will automatically disabling .

Comment: Hi Amit, thanks for the suggestion. I'll check it in about 3 to 4 days as i'm out now and will revert if it works

Comment: This is not a proper full solution. The link to "Cart" at the top of the page disappears, but i still have the "add to cart" buttons on each product, which leads to an empty page.

Answer (score 1):

You can Also disable Checkout following way.

Admin > System > Configuration > SALES > Checkout >Checkout option > 
Enable Onepage Checkout > yes/no

Default  Magento Provided way